# Делаю сайт с bootstrap 4. При наведении на блок, другие блоки смещаются - как пофиксить?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

Создал container в нем несколько строчек .row с колонками .col. Есть идея чтобы при наведении на любую колонку .col выпадала из под нее меню с ссылками. Но, как бы я не шаманил все остальные колонки что внизу просто отлетают на приличное расстояние.

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4  job-type">Проектными работами <ul class="list">
            <li>Архитектурно-строительная и конструктивная часть</li>
                <li>Инженерные сети (ЭТР+ВК+ОВ)</li>
                    <li>Вынос геодезической основы, разбивка осей здания</li>
                        <li>Геологические изыскания</li>

        </ul></div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Фундаментальными работами</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Монтаж стен и перекрытий</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство кровли дома</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство фасада</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Электромонтажные работы</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство водопровода и канализации</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Отделочные работы</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Создание проекта</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Вот css:

```
    .list{
     display: none;
    }
   .job-type:hover .list{
    opacity: block;
    }
    .job-type:hover{
    border:1px solid white;
    background:rgba(0,0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size:40px;
   }
   .job-type{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
   }
```

Пробовал position relative - и чот и никаких изменений

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам примерный вариант (окончательную красоту сами наведёте). Меню (которое скрыто и появляется при наведении) должно быть спозиционировано абсолютно. Тогда оно не будет отталкивать вниз другие блоки, а раскроется поверх них:

```css
.list{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     color: white;
     background-color: rgba(0,0, 0, 0.8);
     font-size: 14px;
     z-index: 1;
    }
   .job-type:hover .list{
    display: block;
    }
    .job-type:hover{
    background:rgba(0,0, 0, 0.8);
   }
   .job-type{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid white;
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4  job-type">Проектными работами
          <ul class="list">
              <li>Архитектурно-строительная и конструктивная часть</li>
              <li>Инженерные сети (ЭТР+ВК+ОВ)</li>
              <li>Вынос геодезической основы, разбивка осей здания</li>
              <li>Геологические изыскания</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Фундаментальными работами</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Монтаж стен и перекрытий</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство кровли дома</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство фасада</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Электромонтажные работы</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Устройство водопровода и канализации</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Отделочные работы</div>
        <div class="col-4 job-type">Создание проекта</div>
    </div>
</div>
```